# Yahoo Finance Can't Download Fund History CSV File For Certain Funds

Tags: csv, download, yahoo-finance

I am currently trying to download a number of Mutual Fund Price Histories from Yahoo Finance in CSV format. However, I can only access data for about half of the funds I have tried so far. For example, I try to access the data for the fund 'AXA Sterling Crdt Shrt Dura Bd R Net Inc (GB00B5SPX913.L)' using:

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GB00B5SPX913.L

but this results in the message 'Sorry, the page requested was not found'

However, when I go to the URL:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GB00B5SPX913.L/history?period1=1441321200&period2=1489881600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

I can see the financial history for this fund.

I'd be grateful if someone could assist me please :)

Why won't it allow me to download this data as a CSV file?

Is there any one else who has found this issue and found a way around it?

Simon